# Unable to install vaadin-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, vaadin

I'm getting below error when I'm trying to install vaadin-cli. Any suggestion to fix this would be appreciated?

```
C:\Users\sanga\Desktop\Ela\mancala>npm install -g @vaadin/vaadin-cli --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.com/@vaadin%2fvaadin-cli - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@vaadin/vaadin-cli@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sanga\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-25T19_52_17_950Z-debug-0.log
```

My node and npm version is mentioned below :

```
C:\Users\sanga\Desktop\Ela\mancala>node -v
v18.14.2

C:\Users\sanga\Desktop\Ela\mancala>npm -v
9.5.1
```

I tried to uninstalling and installing node but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@vaadin/cli` instead of `@vaadin/vaadin-cli`:

```js
npm install -g @vaadin/cli --force
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It helped me. I'm able to install vaadin-cli now :)